# Natted ip with ReplicaSet

Tags: mongodb

We have configured MongoDB Replica Set using the local IP of the server.

`config = {_id: 'Prod', members: [
               {_id: 0, host: '10.10.194.22:27017'},
               {_id: 1, host: '10.10.194.23:27017'},
               {_id: 2, host: '10.10.194.24:27017'},
           {_id: 3, host: '10.10.194.25:27017', arbiterOnly: true}]
           };`

It's working absolutely fine for me . Problem starts when we are trying to populate data from Eclips.

We are connecting the DB using public IP, which we have tested the connecting using Mongo-Explorer.

While populating the data, it's trying to connect to the local IP of the Server & that throws the error "connection timed out" .

-Tarak

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you connect to MongoDB as a single node, the client driver will connect with the address you specified.

However, if you connect to MongoDB as a replica set, the client driver will ask the server for the replica set configuration, and then use the host names or IP addresses in the configuation. If the database server nodes are not reachable from your client using those host names or IP addresses, it will not work.

If you are using Java, the difference is which constructor you use for the Mongo object. If you use one of the List contstructors, even with only one object in the List, it will connect as a replica set, so it would not work for you. Other drivers have similar mechanisms but you didn't mention which driver you are using.

But if you connect to one node of the replica set as a single node, this should work. I would not say it is recommended, but it should work.